# Implementing Alpha-Equivalence in haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I want to define Alpha-Equivalence using this data definition

```
type Sym = Char
data Exp = Var Sym | App Term Exp | Lam Sym Exp 
deriving (Eq, Read, Show)
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please don't delete and run away once you have received your answer

Comment: See https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/bound for an explanation of techniques to allow you _not_ to have to do alpha-equivalence

Comment: fyi you don't need to do alpha conversions to implement a lambda calculus evaluator

Answer (score 3):

One way is to convert names to De Bruijn indices, where e.g. `0` refers to the variable bound by the innermost enclosing lambda, `1` the next enclosing lambda, and so on. So instead of *absolute* names, you use *relative* indices, giving you alpha-equivalence and capture-avoiding substitution for free:

```
type Sym = Char
data Exp = Var Sym | App Exp Exp | Lam Sym Exp
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

type Ind = Int
data Exp' = Var' Ind | App' Exp' Exp' | Lam' Exp'
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show)
```

To do the conversion, you just keep an *environment* of the names in scope:

```
db :: Exp -> Exp'
db = go []
  where

    -- If we see a variable, we look up its index in the environment.
    go env (Var sym) = case findIndex (== sym) env of
      Just ind -> Var' ind
      Nothing -> error "unbound variable"

    -- If we see a lambda, we add its variable to the environment.
    go env (Lam sym exp) = Lam' (go (sym : env) exp)

    -- The other cases are straightforward.
    go env (App e1 e2) = App' (go env e1) (go env e2)
```

Now, alpha equivalence is simple:

```
alphaEq x y = db x == db y
-- or:
alphaEq = (==) `on` db
```

Examples:

```
-- λx.x ~ λy.y
Lam 'x' (Var 'x') `alphaEq` Lam 'y' (Var 'y')  ==  True

-- λx.λy.λz.xz(yz)
s1 = Lam 'x' $ Lam 'y' $ Lam 'z'
  $ Var 'x' `App` Var 'z' `App` (Var 'y' `App` Var 'z')

-- λa.λb.λc.ac(bc)
s2 = Lam 'a' $ Lam 'b' $ Lam 'c'
  $ Var 'a' `App` Var 'c' `App` (Var 'b' `App` Var 'c')

-- λa.λb.λc.ab(ac)
s3 = Lam 'a' $ Lam 'b' $ Lam 'c'
  $ Var 'a' `App` Var 'b' `App` (Var 'a' `App` Var 'c')

s1 `alphaEq` s2  ==  True
s1 `alphaEq` s3  ==  False
```