# Haskell Lambda Alpha Equivalence

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I am trying to  write down an alpha equivalence function in Haskell for lambda.

`data Expr = App Expr Expr | Lam Int Expr | Var Int  deriving (Show,Eq)`

I've read some online resources but I can't transform them into code. 
Thank you

Comment: The implementation. If someone can give me some code in haskell for alpha equivalence on this Data type

Comment: Can you show us what you’ve tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Alpha-Equivalence in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316605/implementing-alpha-equivalence-in-haskell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So two expressions are alpha equivalent if you can turn one into the other by renaming variables. So how could we capture this? There are two main ways:

1. Keep track of which variable names must correspond to one another in the two expressions.
2. (Explicitly or implicitly) convert into a form where instead of variable names, the number of the enclosing scope is used.

Let’s go for the first one

```
-- helper functions for association lists
type Alist a = [(a,a)]
assoc, rassoc :: Eq a => a -> Alist a -> a
assoc x ((a,b):ps) = if x == a then b else assoc x ps
rassoc x = assoc x . map (\(a,b) -> (b,a))
acons a b l = (a,b):l

(=*=) :: Expr -> Expr -> Bool
a =*= b = eq [] a b where
  eq l (Lam n x) (Lam m y) = eq (acons n m l) x y
  eq l (Var n) (Var m) = assoc n l == m && n == rassoc m l
  eq l (App f u) (App g v) = eq l f g && eq l u v
  eq l _ _ = False
```

The only real subtlety here is the case of comparing variables. To check that `x` and `y` are alpha equivalent we need to check that the binding for `x` corresponds to a binding of `y` AND the binding for `y` corresponds to a binding for `x`. Otherwise we might say that `\x.\y.x` is alpha equivalent to `\y.\y.y`.

It’s also worth noting that malformed expressions will result in match failures.

Here’s how to implicitly do the second option:

```
varN :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
varN a xs = v 0 xs where
  v n (x:xs) = if a == x then n else v (n+1) xs

a =*= b = eq [] [] a b in where
  eq k l (Lam n x) (Lam m y) = eq (n:k) (m:l) x y
  eq k l (Var n) (Var m) = varN n k == varN m l
  eq k l (App f u) (App g v) = eq k l f g && eq k l u v
  eq k l _ _ = False
```

Hopefully you can see that these are equivalent

Answer (score 0):

```hs
type SymToSym = Map String String

alphaEqHelper :: Lexp -> Lexp -> SymToSym -> SymToSym -> Bool
alphaEqHelper (Lambda lname lfunc) (Lambda rname rfunc) ltor rtol =
  alphaEqHelper lfunc rfunc (Map.insert lname rname ltor) (Map.insert rname lname rtol)
alphaEqHelper (Apply lfunc largs) (Apply rfunc rargs) ltor rtol =
  alphaEqHelper lfunc rfunc ltor rtol && alphaEqHelper largs rargs ltor rtol
alphaEqHelper (Atom lname) (Atom rname) ltor rtol
  | Map.member lname ltor && Map.member rname rtol =
    fromJust (Map.lookup lname ltor) == rname
      && fromJust (Map.lookup rname rtol) == lname
  | Map.member lname ltor || Map.member rname rtol = False
  | otherwise = lname == rname
alphaEqHelper _ _ _ _ = False

alphaEq :: Lexp -> Lexp -> Bool
alphaEq llexp rlexp =
  alphaEqHelper
    llexp
    rlexp
    Map.empty
    Map.empty
```